# How do I cook frozen pastry

Tags: oven, pastry, frozen

I bought it from a farm shop (meadow fresh) as pictured. I know it goes in the oven.
But what temperature or duration.

Unfortunately it came with no instructions and I forgot to look for some when I bought it.

[image: pastry]

*Update:*

I followed the instructions from the answer below, and these things expanded to 3 times their size overnight, and 5 times their original size when cooked. They were fantastic. Leaving out overnight, then 10 mins at 190c was just right.
(the clue was in the packaging, as the website did contain instructions as suggested.)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trader Joe's sells frozen mini-croissants. The instructions for them are, as far as I remember: set them out overnight (or equivalent) on a lightly greased cookie sheet to "proof" (or "rise"). In the morning you may want to brush a thin coating of egg wash on them before cooking to make them shiny & beautiful (this is optional). Then cook in preheated - 350 degree F - oven for 15 to 20 minutes or until croissants are quite golden brown. (TJ's says that if they are just *light* brown they are not done on the inside.) Then they should cool for 10 minutes before serving.

The "mini-croissants" are actually fairly big in my opinion. Not sure exactly the size of the items you have, but if they are significantly bigger than those "mini"s, you might need to add a teeny bit of time, but 15 - 20 minutes is pretty vague anyway, so I would say just watch the color. Dark chocolate-brown is a little too done; and pale beige is not done enough.

Alternatively, have you checked the website listed on the plastic bag they came in? Maybe there are instructions there. I can't really read it in your photo, but it starts out "www...."!

OK, new UK info; in case these are "Field Fare" all-butter croissants,

https://field-fare.com/product/all-butter-croissant/  says:

"Cooking Instructions

Spread out on a baking tray and leave to prove overnight at room temperature.  Egg wash and bake in a pre-heated oven at 190°C/375ºF/Gas Mark 5 for 8-10 minutes, until golden brown.

Important Information

These cooking instructions are a guide only. Your appliance may have a different power rating, so please adjust accordingly"

Comment: Thankyou. Did not occur to let it thaw overnight. I tried Google but it can up with nothing useful. Didn't even realise there was a web address on the bag lol. Great answers thanks.

Comment: The field fare ones work very well if you follow the instructions. Again though, they're better if you err on the side of over-done,at least for eating warm.

Comment: @ChrisH I did them for 10 minutes and it was great. updated my question with a picture of the results. Thanks :) Didnt realise the instructions were on the link on the packaging. They were field fare. And leaving them out overnight i would never have guessed. For some reason i thought you cooked them from frozen :)

Comment: My local farm shop does these (or used to) and for a while the till printed the instructions on the receipt - again, not where you'd think of looking. IMO these are the closest you'll get to a French bakery without living near one

Comment: @Doomsknight Nice follow up! Thanks for posting your results!